# How to distinguish dynamically generated button on selection using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uibutton

In my iPhone app, I have array of buttons that are dynamically generated based on user selection.

How do I distinguish selected button from others?

I want that when user select the other button the previously selected button should go back to its normal state in terms of its looks. I am unable to revert the previously selected buttons to its normal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of the buttons. You can loop through your array and check if it is the one that was clicked.

```
- (IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)sender {
  for(int i; i < [array count]; i++){
     if((UIButton *)sender == (UIButton *)[array objectAtIndex:i])
        //do something
     else
        //do something else
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Use tag to identify the button. 
At the time of creating buttons you can assign tag as number to the button and use the same to identify.

yourButton.tag = intNumber;

Answer (score 1):

Try setting **tag** for each button,using

```
yourButton.tag=intValue; //intValue>0
```

Your buttonAction should be as follows,

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
```

Save the previously selected tag, and change the value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through your subviews and set for all the old style:

```
- (void)highlightImgWithID:(int)packID {
    [self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [(UIImageView*)obj setHighlighted:([obj tag] == IDtoSelectNext)];
        }
    }];
}
```

The sample is how I currently implement it in my App with `UIImageView`'s you can change it to work with buttons.

Comment: forgot to say that I'm using the tag elsewhere so I couldn't use the tag as identifier which one is selected